# problem displaying webpage on different computers

Tags: jquery, hardware, screen-size

I have a very weird problem.
I have a webpage that displays some graphs using Jquery. This page works fine on my laptop & my other colleagues laptop.
But there is one particular PC that does not display the webpage properly.  I thought that it might be a browser issue but when I connected remotely to that PC from my laptop, the webpage displayed the graphs perfectly.
I am not sure if this is an hardware related problem, my laptop's screen size is 15" while the PC that gives problem has a screen size of 40"
Please help.

Regards,
Krum

Comment: Let me guess, the one PC in particular is owned by your client.

Comment: In a way..Its kind of a demo PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once had to check the DPI settings on a particular machine because of weird rendering issues, and that fixed it.

Windows 7:

Control Panel > Appearance and Personalization > Display > Set custom text size (DPI)

Comment: I currently don't have access to it, but I'll check it asap. Thanks

Comment: The screen resolution was the issue, I am trying to add some CSS around it so that it can work for all resolutions.

Comment: I wouldn't bother applying CSS fixes for different DPI settings. You will never fix all possible settings, it's just not worth it.